# .join for possible empty Queue in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, blockingqueue

I'm trying to implement a `Queue` processing thread in python as follows:

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import sys    

class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        # Call thread constructor
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            task = self.queue.get()
            # doTask()
            self.queue.task_done()

queue = Queue()
thread = Worker(thread)
thread.start()

while True:
    inp = user_input()

    if condition(inp):
        queue.put(sometask())
    else:
        queue.join()
        thread.join()
        sys.exit(0)
```

In this example, suppose user decides to `exit` without adding any item to queue. Then my thread will be blocking at `self.queue.get` and I `queue.join()` won't work. Because of that, I can't perform a proper `exit`.

How can I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `Queue.get` a timeout and use a stop event:

```
from Queue import Queue, Empty
from threading import Thread, Event
import sys

class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, stop):
        # Call thread constructor
        self.queue = queue
        self.stop = stop
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop.is_set():
            try:
                task = self.queue.get(timeout=1)
            except Empty:
                continue
            # doTask()
            self.queue.task_done()

queue = Queue()
stop = Event()
thread = Worker(queue, stop)
thread.start()

while True:
    inp = raw_input()

    if inp:
        queue.put(inp)
    else:
        stop.set()
        queue.join()
        thread.join()
        sys.exit(0)
```

This adds a condition to the Thread worker's while loop so that you can stop it whenever. You have to give the `Queue.get` a timeout so that it can check the stop event periodically.

## Update

You can use a sentinel rather than timeout:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import sys

_sentinel = Object()

class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, sentinel=None):
        # Call thread constructor
        self.queue = queue
        self.sentinel = sentinel
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            task = self.queue.get()
            if task is self.sentinel:
                self.queue.task_done()
                return
            # doTask()
            self.queue.task_done()


queue = Queue()
thread = Worker(queue, sentinel=_sentinel)
thread.start()

while True:
    inp = raw_input()

    if inp:
        queue.put(inp)
    else:
        queue.put(_sentinel)
        queue.join()
        thread.join()
        sys.exit(0)
```

Thanks to Bakuriu for the sentinel = Object() suggestion.

Comment: That is a good idea. However, I will have to iterate over loop in each 1s. Can I trigger some event by which I can unblock `queue.get` dynamically?

Comment: @niyasc Which loop are you referring to? The Thread workers loop or the loop that is putting items on the Queue? And why do you need to iterate over it each 1s?

Comment: I was referring to loop in `Worker` class. As per this implementation `get` method will timeout in `1s` and it will go for next iteration. Is n't it?

Comment: @niyasc That is correct, the `get` call will block for 1s and then continue to the next iteration of the loop if it is empty. So you would prefer not to iterate every second if the queue is empty, is that correct? Sorry I didn't understand your question, I must be a little thick headed today.

Comment: I'd replace `_sentinel = 'STOP'` with `_sentinel=object()`. Why? Because if the tasks in the queue are strings the end could be triggered by a valid task. Note that with strings using `is` to try to avoid this isn't safe due to string interning (i.e. even with `if task is self.sentinel` a valid task could trigger the end). Sentinel values should be fresh `object()` instances so that there's no way of something be compared equal to them (techincally you should also use `task is self.sentinel` to be 100% foolproof).

Comment: Thanks @Bakuriu, that is great advice.